# Terminate a workflow for an item that no longer exists?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, powershell

I need to finish a workflow that is still running in a document library that no longer has items (all were deleted, from de Library and the Recycle Bin).

Maybe with Powershell, but all the solutions I find make a loop in the elements (scenario that doesn't work here).

SharePoint Server 2016 - Workflow SHP 2013 (NO Nintex).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you removed the items from the 2nd Stage Recycle Bin (**Site Collection Recycle Bin**).

[image]

> Once the document is deleted, it moved to the 1st stage recycle bin.
>   It stays there based on the web application recycle bin setting that (default is 30 days). 
>   After this period finished (30 days) or it was deleted from the 1st stage recycle bin, it moved to the 2nd stage recycle bin it also called `Site Collection Recycle Bin`.